# React isn't reading local images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

I am trying to create an image slider for the projects in my portfolio. I created a seed file with the local paths to the images and alts for each image. As I am trying to map the photos across the projects page, I am able to see all of the alt values, and the first image, but the images succeeding that are not being read.

Seed File:

```
import Crescendo from "../assets/images/crescendo 2 (1).png";
import Donate from "../assets/images/donate homepage.png";
import Password from "../assets/images/password 2.png";
import SuperWiki from "../assets/images/super hero 2.jpg";
import Calculator from '../assets/images/react-calculator.png';

export const SliderData = [
    {
        image: Crescendo,
        alt: "Crescendo, Full-stack project"
    },
    {
        image: Donate,
        alt: "Donate, a MERN stack project for displaying charities worth donating to"
    },
    {
        image: Password,
        alt: "A frontend designed and functional password generator"
    },
    {
        image: SuperWiki,
        alt: "Super Hero Wiki, designed with Marvel API to provide results for user's searches"
    },
    {
        image: Calculator,
        alt: "A calculator built using React and Javascript"
    }
];
```

Component file:

```
import React from 'react'
import {SliderData} from './SliderData';

function Projects() {
  return (
   <>
    {SliderData.map((slide, index) =>{
      return(
        <img src={slide.image} alt={slide.alt}></img>
      )
    })}
   </>
  )
}

export default Projects
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**I think you must replace "../" to be like "./" ( one dot )**

```
import image001 from "./assets/images/001.jpg";
import image002 from "./assets/images/002.png";

export const SliderData = [
    {
        image: image001,
        alt: "Crescendo, Full-stack project"
    },
    {
        image: image002,
        alt: "Donate, a MERN stack project for displaying charities worth donating to"
    },
];
```

```
import {SliderData} from './SliderData';
function App() {
  return (
    <>
    {SliderData.map((slide, index) =>{
      return(
          <img src={slide.image} alt={slide.alt}></img>
      )
    })}
   </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Result :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the server and all of the images are suddenly appearing in the map. I guess it was just a glitch in the react server.